# Como simular la función REDONDEAR.MAS

Tags: excel, vb6, vbscript

Estoy intentando recrear en **VBScript** el funcionamiento de la función:

```
REDONDEAR.MAS(numero;**-2**)
```

La cual es una función de Excel. A pesar de intentarlo cada vez mas no lo puedo lograr.

Ejemplo, si tengo la cantidad 994978 como puedo obtener el valor 995000?.

Answer (score 2):

Buen día,

Lo que buscas es poder redondear a un múltiplo con [`REDOND.MULT`](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/funci%C3%B3n-redond-mult-c299c3b0-15a5-426d-aa4b-d2d5b3baf427)

Ejemplo:

```
REDOND.MULT(994978, 5000)
```

Esto devuelve 995000

**Edición:** Para hacerlo de forma manual puedes usar la siguiente fórmula

```
5000 - (994978 Mod 5000) + 994978
```

Comment: Buen dia. Yo busco recrear el mismo funcionamiento (Funcion nativa de Excel) en el lenguaje de programación VBScript

Comment: Edité la respuesta con la fórmula para hacerlo

Comment: Muchas gracias, sin embargo. No genera el mismo funcionamiento que la función REDONDEAR.MAS(numero;-2). Si intento colocar otras cantidades no  lo hace igual.

Comment: ¿Cómo lo estás haciendo? ¿Qué cantidad no da el resultado?